Where should I perform EMSA-PSS-encoding (apart from the first hashing step) in a remote signing scenario, on client or server?
I would like to set up a remote signing scenario in which

local: on a client a document exists that is to be signed
remote: a private key for signing resides on a server

Furthermore, I would like to implement this using RSASSA-PSS. According to RFC 8017 sec. 8.1.1 and sec. 9.1.1 the signing process consists of the following steps:

$M \mapsto Hash(M) =: mHash$ (being the first step of the EMSA-PSS-encoding)
all remaining steps of EMSA-PSS-encoding (padding/salt/masking), producing $=: EM$ (encoded message)
sign EM (converted to an integer) with RSA primitive using secret key and modulus, producing $=: signature$

In my setup, for privacy reasons, I want to keep the plain message M hidden from the server, thus I would perform step 1 on the client.
Obviously, step 3 will be performed by the server.
My question relates to step 2:
What would be the best approach from a security point of view:

variant A: performing step 2 locally on the client and sending $EM$ to the server = 1+2 local, 3 remote (i.e. performing the whole EMSA-PSS-encoding locally) or
variant B: sending $mHash$ to the server in order to perform step 2 there remotely = 1 local, 2+3 remote?

Is one of these variants more vulnerable to classical attack scenarios than the other?
update 2024-10-31:
In the meantime I found that RFC 8017 sec. 9.1 note 3 states:

Without compromising the security proof for RSASSA-PSS, one may perform Steps 1 and 2 of EMSA-PSS-ENCODE and EMSA-PSS-VERIFY (the application of the hash function to the message) outside the module that computes the rest of the signature operation, so that mHash rather than the message M itself is input to the module.

It is further argued that this might be useful e.g. with respect to the module's I/O bandwith, which is a different reason than mine, and one would have to consider the 'server' in my setup as 'module' in the quoted note. But as far as the comparison holds, in light of the note, variant B seems to me the right one.
It would still be interesting if someone could give their professional opinion on this.

Generally the hash-only A step should be preferred as it describes pre-hashing. Not so much out of security, but it is likely the most compatible version.
Many libraries and implementations  - unfortunately not all - allow to hash the message outside of the signature generation device. This way the initial steps are not specific the signature generation algorithm.
Padding may be security sensitive as it may influence side channel attacks. So in general you'd not do this out of the signature generation device, even if it doesn't compromise the private key directly through mathematical means.
The latter point is harder to substantiate, but since it isn't the only reason I think it doesn't matter.

Beware that if the message can be guessed then the server could try and guess it and validate it against the hash or against the padding. So beware that not all messages will be equally safe.

PS sorry, I entirely missed this question. Hope it is still of some use. Even if it isn't please indicate if it solves your problem as it might help others.
